# Increase performance on OleDB insert into statement, BeginTransaction CommitTransaction

Tags: c#, oledb

I have written to append functions that insert data from custom c# list into MSAccess.

The first simply sets up a new connection for each individual recordset:

```
        public static void appenddatatotable(string connectionstring, string tablename, string[] values)
    {

            var myconn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);


            var cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + tablename + " ([RunDate],[ReportingGroup], [Tariff], [Year]) VALUES(@RunDate, @ReportingGroup, @Tariff, @Year)";

            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new[] { new OleDbParameter("@RunDate", values[0]), new OleDbParameter("@ReportingGroup", values[1]), new OleDbParameter("@Tariff", values[2]), new OleDbParameter("@Year", values[3])});
            cmd.Connection = myconn;
            myconn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myconn.Close();

    }
```

I then simply loop over my list of values and call this function on each iteration. This works fine but is slow.

In the second function I tried to include the loop in the function and work with BeginTransction and Committransaction:

```
        public static void appenddatatotable2(string connectionstring, string tablename, string datstr, List<PowRes> values)
    {

        var myconn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);
        int icounter = 0;

        var cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbTransaction trans = null;

        cmd.Connection = myconn;
        myconn.Open();
        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            if (icounter == 0)
            {
                trans = cmd.Connection.BeginTransaction();
                cmd.Transaction = trans;
            }

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + tablename + " ([RunDate],[ReportingGroup], [Tariff], [Year]) VALUES(@RunDate, @ReportingGroup, @Tariff, @Year)";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.yr))
                item.yr = "";

            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new[] { new OleDbParameter("@RunDate", datstr), new OleDbParameter("@ReportingGroup", item.RG), new OleDbParameter("@Tariff", item.tar), new OleDbParameter("@Year", item.yr)});
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            icounter++;
            if (icounter >= 500)
            {
                trans.Commit();
                icounter = 0;
            }
        }
        if (icounter > 0)
        {
            trans.Commit();
        }


        myconn.Close();

    }
```

This also works fine but is EVEN slower.

Is my code wrong? How could I speed up the multiple inserts?

Thanks!

Comment: unrelated to the question, but very important: you should be using `using` statements here, for both `myconn` and `cmd`, to ensure they are cleaned up even if something goes wrong. Probably also `trans`, but that is complicated by your unusual usage (assigning late, etc)

Comment: Thanks Marc. good point, I will clean that up! Any ideas on why the second might be slower though?

Comment: @npvh because you have added another overhead that is transaction.

Comment: @npvh when it comes to access, all expectations of sanity fly out the window; however, there is no reason we should expect it to be any *faster*, and every reason we should expect it to be *slower* (we have added overheads in terms of transaction management)

Comment: You need to look a bit deeper into this - what is actually *slow*, your code or the DB? Once you know where the bottle neck is you can look at how to optimize.

Comment: which to me means then I was not doing what I thought I was doing....:) what I want to do is to pool parameters and insert them at once to reduce network traffic. How would I do that?

Comment: @James: it is the network, if I put the DB on C drive then the first one is reasonably fast. Because it is the network I wanted to reduce the calls to the db and pool the inserts but I obviously didnt really do that...

Comment: Have you looked at [SqlBulkCopy](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/122498/using-sqlbulkcopy-for-high-performance-inserts/)? Depending on the number of inserts you are doing it could make the difference.

Answer (score 1):

did not test, just my guess for your second function: you add too many parameters to the same command over the loop - cmd.Parameters were never cleared before each usage..

normally committing large set of commands within one connection is much faster than doing them one by one at single connection.

another way to speed up your inserts is to dump all your insert statements into a long text, separated with semicolon, and then fire a commit in one go (i am not sure whether msAccess supports it or not)

EDIT:

to combine the update command into one text:

```
var updates = values.Select(x => string.Format("INSERT INTO myTable ([RunDate],[ReportingGroup], [Tariff], [Year]) VALUES({0}, {1}, {2}, {3})",
                datstr, x.RG, x.tar, x.yr))
                .Aggregate((m, n) => m + ";" + n);
cmd.CommandText = update;
```

Though this could have sql injection issues.

Comment: thanks Rex. I have to admit I thought that is what I was doing. How do I pool insert statements and then use one commit?

Comment: see the edit part for the combined text command. but this might not be a good practice to put all the parameters into plain text, for security reasons....

Comment: thanks for the anser. But if you look at other stackoverflow questions, (and as you said) you can get completely messed up strings depending on variable names and user inputs - hence I would rather not go down this route.

Answer (score 1):

this should be significantly faster than all of your exiting versions

```
public static void appenddatatotable2(string connectionstring, string tablename, string datstr, List<PowRes> values)
        {
            string commandText = "INSERT INTO " + tablename + " ([RunDate],[ReportingGroup], [Tariff], [Year]) VALUES(@RunDate, @ReportingGroup, @Tariff, @Year)";
            using (var myconn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                myconn.Open();
                using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    foreach (var item in values)
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = commandText;
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new[] { new OleDbParameter("@RunDate", datstr), new OleDbParameter("@ReportingGroup", item.RG), new OleDbParameter("@Tariff", item.tar), new OleDbParameter("@Year", item.yr) });
                        cmd.Connection = myconn;
                        cmd.Prepare(); 
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
```

Comment: It might be worth just documenting *why* this is faster for clarification.

Comment: @Ehsan: thanks for the asnwer. I see that this is saver because it uses using as suggested by Marc. But it seems not different to my first version as it connects and executes each item individually. Or do I not get it?

Comment: actually it is a combination of your 2 versions. Here connection is opened only once, similarly command is created only once. It will only take that time that is taken by access

Comment: @Ehsan: Got it, thanks. But it should still be possible to increase  performance to also write once into DB as opposed to line by line. No?

Comment: well there was one more tweak of prepare command that i have added in my code

Comment: "*connection is opened only once, similarly command is created only once*" - sorry but the OP's code already does this. And for the record, the `using` is not a performance optimization it's a housekeeping syntax which ensures `Dispose` is called on the object. The main differences here are a) you don't use a transaction, b) you don't update a counter variable on each iteration, c) You don't then check that counter variable on each iteration and finally d) you clear the parameters list on each iteration.

Comment: @James his method was taking one row values and he was opening connection for each insert. Look at his code and mine before you decide. I have given my statement because he thought that my code is similar to his first version. Which infact is not

Comment: @EhsanUllah I have looked at the OP's code and he opens the connection *before* the `for` loop and closes it after, not for each insert. Also the OP is using batch inserts which your code does not cover (which appears to be in 500 inserts per batch). For bulk inserts which are all dependant of each other a transaction is generally recommended.

Comment: @James you must had seen his second option, whereas mine is a variation of his both versions.

Comment: @EhsanUllah my point is this is pretty much just a neater version of the code the OP already has - excluding the transaction. Like I said in the first comment, you should elaborate on *why* it's faster because if your answer is "it doesn't use a transaction" then it's not really much use (if the OP *needs* to do batch inserts).

Comment: @James: it is true, in my second version I dont open a connection on each iteration and I was trying to do a bulk insert (hence the counter to 500 and the use of transaction) but the performance gain doesnt show in the run time. How would you suggest doing it? In my second code, when does it actually paste in DB? On Execute or on Commit trans?

Comment: @npvh "*but the performance gain doesn't show in the run time*" - transactions aren't designed for performance, they are designed for atomicity/consistency & control. If you are looking for performance my advice is keep the client light & the DB heavy (i.e. let the DB do as much of the work as possible, or at least they heavy lifting). As with any command the data is inserted into the DB when you call `ExecuteNonQuery`, however, if wrapped in a transaction the data is inserted into a *temp* table first (to allow for rollbacks etc.) and then on `COMMIT` inserts the data into the correct table.

Comment: Also, like you have already mentioned the root cause of your problem is a slow network therefore the bulk of your performance problem is probably due to latency. I'd look at fixing that before anything else (if you can).